# Use limit to show convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have earlier showed that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{6}.$$ Then I have to use this to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$ is convergent. But I can't see how I can use it? Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You have shown that $\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sim \frac{1}{6n^3}$, so ...

Answer (score 3):

From $\lim_{n\to \infty}|n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)|=\frac{1}{6}$ we see that there is $N$ such that

$$|n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)| \le 1$$

for $n>N$, hence

$$|\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)| \le \frac{1}{n^3}$$

for $n>N$.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit shows that $\left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right) = O(\frac{1}{n^3})$. The RHS is a positive term of a convergent series. Then, use the comparison principle to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n = \frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \geq 0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ , $a_n \sim \frac{1}{6n^3}$ as $n\to +\infty$ and the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} $ is convergent.

Therefore the series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ is convergent by the Limit Comparison Test.